# Calculate values of same distribution with given min, max and resolution

Tags: javascript, math

I need some help to build a mathematical function, which takes three parameters (min, max, resolution) and returns values (nearly) in this distribution:

```
5
10.2
13.45
15.4
16.7
17.35
18
```

In this example, min is `5`, max is `18` and there are `7` steps.

So I calculated the range, which is `max - min` (=13) and used these percentages (can be adjusted a bit, if calculation gets easier)

```
40%
65%
80%
90%
95%
100%
```

of the range, which is added to the min value.

```
13 * 0.4 + 5 = 10.2
13 * 0.65 + 5 = 13.45
...
```

The graph of these values, should be the same if the resolution is higher: If there are 100 instead of 7 steps, the distribution/graph should be the same. But how do I calculate the value of each step?

[image]

```
function calcValues(min, max, steps) {
    const data = []
    const range = max - min
    for (i = 0; i < steps; i++) {
        const value = range * whichValueIsNeededHere + min
        data.push(value)
    }
    return data
}
```

Comment: Should be `const value = range * whichValueIsNeededHere + min`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First Approach**:

This graph seems close to the `y = a(x^3) + b(x^2) + c(x) + d`. I was able to retrieve the values of **a, b, c and d** with the help of the given `(x,y)` pairs. The values are:

**a = 0.08125**

**b = -1.421875**

**c = 8.896875**

**d = -2.55625**

Now, if you substitute different `x` values, you will be getting exact values (or close) to `y`. The minimal difference in the `y` values could be because of some constant which has not been taken into consideration in the equation (but like I said, the difference is very minimal).

The approach to use this equation is as follows:

1. Divide the `max(x) - min(x)` by `steps` to get the `stepX`.
2. Add the `stepX` to different values of `x` (within the range of x
   values i.e. [1,7]).
3. Substitute `x` values in the equation to get different `y` values.

Note - ***stepX** is each step that needs to be taken to go from **min** to **max** in the X-axis.*

This is a manual process for you to test the integrity of the graph for different **(x,y)** pairs.

**Second Approach**:

As you confirmed that you need the function to work only for a particular graph, we can use the given `(x,y)` pairs as the reference in the program. Well, this could be a trick or hack, whatever you say!!.

```js
function traverseGraph(source, destination, steps) {
    // As the scenario is for a particular graph only, we can use the example for the reference
    const xValues = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
    const yPattern = [5, 10.2, 13.45, 15.4, 16.7, 17.35, 18];

    const diffX = destination[0] - source[0];
    const diffY = destination[1] - source[1];

    const stepX = diffX / (steps - 1);
    
    const ratio = (xValues.length - 1) / (steps - 1);

    const points = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < steps; i++) {
        const xIndex = Math.floor(i * ratio);
        const yIndex = Math.min(xIndex + 1, xValues.length - 1);

        const x = source[0] + stepX * i;
        const y = yPattern[xIndex] + (yPattern[yIndex] - yPattern[xIndex]) * (i * ratio - xIndex);

        points.push([x, y]);
    }

    return points;
}

function calcValues(min, max, steps) {
  const source = [1, min];
  const destination = [7, max];
  return traverseGraph(source, destination, steps);
}

console.log(calcValues(5, 18, 20))
```

I tested the output coming from the program and the equation for the same **(x,y)** pairs and again the difference is very minimal. So, I am not sure how much this has helped you but you can give it a try at least from your side using the approaches shared above.

PS - You can use this [link](https://www.mathway.com/popular-problems/Trigonometry/373837) to test the output from the equation.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Yes, I think there is a misunterstanding. I don't need a even distribution. I need to get a graph from these values. And the graph should look like this: https://ibb.co/xCVM08j Using 7 values or 100 values...

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I assume you do have the list of x and y pairs. Can you please share them to derive the equation?

Comment: In the post I wrote the seven y values for x 1-7

Comment: I see a Fibonacci pattern in the unknown value. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: But this works only for 7 steps. If I use `calcValues(5, 18, 20)` I do get negative values. The problem is, the distribution should keep the same if you are using higher resolution. 14 steps should only add values in between, so the graph gets more accurate, but shouldn't change at all.

Comment: Yeah, I will give some more thought to this today. Interesting problem though !!

Comment: I have a question. Do you want a generic function that works for this graph only? or do you want a generic function that works for any graph? I guess it would be hard to do the latter. While I do have some progress on the former case. Let me know your thoughts on this.

Comment: Should be a generic function for this graph, which could have different min, max and step values.